# Time difference in sql. Totaltime over midnight

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

Really need some help here.

Having a table with the following columns

```
startdate, stopdate, starttime, stoptime, totaltime
```

They are in format `YYYY-MM-DD` and `HH-MM`

How do i get the `totaltime` in `HH-MM` format (sometimes the start and stop passes midnight)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use  TIMEDIFF will give the return  in 00:00:00.00000 // this format

```
TIMEDIFF('2013-11-20 12:01:00', '2010-11-19 12:00:00')
```

or you can covert to sec

```
TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2013-11-20 12:01:00', '2010-11-19 12:00:00'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```sql
UPDATE table1
   SET totaltime = TIMEDIFF(ADDTIME(stopdate, stoptime), 
                            ADDTIME(startdate, starttime));
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf393/1)** demo

**UPDATE:** Here is an example with midnight time.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE Table2
    -> (`startdate` date, 
    ->  `stopdate` date, 
    ->  `starttime` time, 
    ->  `stoptime` time, 
    ->  `totaltime` time);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES
    -> ('2013-11-27', '2013-11-28', '11:00', '00:00', NULL),
    -> ('2013-11-27', '2013-11-28', '00:00', '15:00', NULL),
    -> ('2013-11-27', '2013-11-28', '00:00', '00:00', NULL);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> UPDATE table2
    ->    SET totaltime = TIMEDIFF(ADDTIME(stopdate, stoptime), 
    ->                             ADDTIME(startdate, starttime));
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM table2;
+------------+------------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| startdate  | stopdate   | starttime | stoptime | totaltime |
+------------+------------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 2013-11-27 | 2013-11-28 | 11:00:00  | 00:00:00 | 13:00:00  |
| 2013-11-27 | 2013-11-28 | 00:00:00  | 15:00:00 | 39:00:00  |
| 2013-11-27 | 2013-11-28 | 00:00:00  | 00:00:00 | 24:00:00  |
+------------+------------+-----------+----------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This update worked great for me, but in the case passing midnight i get negative total

Comment: @user3048250 use `timediff( later_date_time, former_date_time )` to get positive result.

Comment: Strange things happening, when passing 00.00 it subtracts stoptime from starttime and make it negative.

Comment: @user3048250 The query itself is perfectly fine. A negative value tells you that your stop datetime  < start datetime. See updated answer for example with all possible combinations of midnight time values. Again it's working just fine.

Comment: Tanks for all the help. Had the wrong types in my table :P Now its working fine. tank you again all of you.